# Loading script after the creation of a textarea tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I'm using this script that binds to all textarea's every second. I'm using it this way as those textareas are loaded dynamicly (after the page is created and this script is loaded). I would rather have a script that is executed everytime a new textarea is created. How could I do that ?

I use this script as a custom header. I don't have access to the rest of the code.

```
function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString) {
    $("textarea").keyup(function (e) {    
        // escape some regex chars
        var escapedString = searchString.replace(/([\\.*+?|()\[\]{}])/g, "\\$1");
        // finds current cursor position
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        // this turns the textarea in a string
        var text = $(this).val();
        //only search for strings just typed
        var stringToSearch = text.substring(pos - searchString.length, pos);

        if (new RegExp(escapedString).test(stringToSearch) === true) {
            //if there is a match put the replaceString in the right place
            var newText = text.substring(0, pos - searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
            $(this).val(newText);
            //adjust the cursor position to the new text
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos, newpos);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(function(){
    autoCorrect("=>", '⇒');
    autoCorrect("->", "→");
    autoCorrect("+-", "±");
    autoCorrect("<=", "≤");
    autoCorrect(">=", "≥");
    autoCorrect("(c)", "©");
    autoCorrect("(e)", "€");      
    autoCorrect("|__", "⌊");
    autoCorrect("__|", "⌋");
    autoCorrect("|--", "⊢");        
    autoCorrect("|==", "⊨"); 
},1000);
```

Comment: as an aside - you'll be wanting to do a setInterval on your doautocorrect rather than an infinitely recursive setTimeout within the function you're doing the setTimeout in !

Comment: @splig Thanks for that, didn't know about setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a delegated event handler, which will auto-bind to any textarea that is later added to the DOM:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function() {
     // $(this) will be a reference to the current textarea
})
```

And you probably should make a autoCorrect go through a set of defined values instead of being called repeatedly for each value on a timer. Just let the keyup event handle things.

```
var replaceThis = "=>,->,+-".split(",")
var withThis = "⇒,→,±".split(",")
```

...then loop through the values.

Comment: The first part works, going to try if I can get the second part to work. Thank you !

Comment: Hi, I have little trouble with doing something like this. Could you help me with implementing your second idea, with this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/4SWy6/ Feel free to ignore this comment.

Comment: Didn't you mean:  
`$("body").on("keyup", "textarea", function() { });`